# Proper git etiquette for users working in mostly-isolated branches?

Tags: git, github, merge, branching-and-merging

Okay, so I'm the GitHub Code QA guy for this project, and I've never done something like this, so I'm trying to learn what I need to be doing while it's happening (which is *terribly* exciting).

The situation is our developers (only 5 of us) are working on separate tasks for a project, and as is proper we are all in our own branches. Now, when we finish that, we merge with master and start on the next task. That's fine, but how, as the QA guy, do I coordinate these merges? How we're doing it now is I resolve the conflicts, but I don't know how to do this. I see my options as:

1. Have the developers notify me when they want me to merge their work into master, at which point I pull to update their branch, then I do the merge, or
2. Have them initiate the merge, then I resolve the conflict.

Currently we are doing the first option. However, to me, 2. sounds like obviously the better choice, but as I understand git, when you try to merge branches, the conflict is generated on the local computer. I don't know of any way to generate the merge conflict and then send it to someone else for them to resolve it.

I suppose I'm also open to discussions about how to restructure this paradigm so that we don't have this kind of issue, too. I just need clarification here, mostly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret behind GitHub Pull Request is that the developers do not have to wait for their work to be complete before notifying you.

As soon as they are pushing to GitHub (on their own branch), they can ask and make a pull request *even if the GitHub repo is the original one* (and not a fork.
You can make PR between branches of *one* repo (instead of PR between a fork repo and the original repo): this is the "[**Shared repository model**](https://help.github.com/articles/types-of-collaborative-development-models/#shared-repository-model)".

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/pull_requests/pull-request-review-edit-branch.png]

The idea behind Pull Request is that they will update themselves every time the developer is pushing to their branch, *even* in case of a **push --force**.

That allows the maintainer to review asynchronously the code *before* any merge, and leave some comment to the code.

It is that kind of permanent review and collaboration which gives a *distributed VCS (Version Control System)* its appeal and strength.
The shorter the feedback loop is, the sooner the fixes and improvements can be part of the final code which will be, in the end, merged to the target branch.